# down() method for migration filling new column

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I have a migration that adds a column to a table. The next migration fills the column with the correct data. The issue I'm having is the `down()` method for that second migration. I don't know how to delete the info that I just inserted. I was going to just

```
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $row->newColumn = null;
 }
```

but I felt like that wasn't very good. Is there a better, cleaner way to do that? Or should both migrations be in one and then I can just drop the column? I felt like one migration shouldn't be doing that much but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single query (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#updates):

`DB::table('table_name')->update(array('column_name' => null));`

Comment: Yeah, I just found that actually. Works I guess. thanks.